# Any idea what this Ampaire plane is?

Tags: aircraft-identification, experimental-aircraft, electric-aircraft

[image]
([Source](https://www.ampaire.com/#flight-plan))
This is certainly not the Ampaire 337 or Electric EEL, which is a converted Cessna 337. It looks like a boundary layer ingestor. Being from Ampaire, it probably is electric or hybrid.

I've tried to find more information about this craft, but failed so far, even from their own website (including the linked page). Google seems to think it's a Learjet. I don't think I've been able to find much, if any other photos of this plane.

The foreground seems to indicate this was a real photo taken from another plane, as you can see window sills, details generally absent in renderings (and many show-off photos). I must admit though, that's not the safest flying around.

Even if it's a rendering, it would probably be a concept. I can't even *name* the plane yet.

It's beautiful.

Comment: This does not appear to be a real picture. It looks computer generated.

Comment: @DeanF. Are you sure? Notice the window sill in the foreground. I don't usually see such things in CGI

Comment: I am not sure at all. But it could be a screen capture from simulator software. Do you have a link where you found this?

Comment: @DeanF. *yes*, I had one all along.

Comment: The only other places I'm finding this photo are news articles which all mention the EEL - the wrong plane. Not a clue about this airplane.

Comment: I am unable to find this specific picture at the link you provided. There are other still pictures under “Media”. Some of them are real and some of them are artist renditions. Can you update your link to point to the actual picture?

Comment: @DeanF. Uh, sorry, wrong page. I'll fix it.

Comment: @DeanF. should work now. You'll have to scroll down a bit.

Comment: Definitely an artist rendering. The chase plane window sill is placed for realism.

Comment: @Abdullah: "Are you sure? Notice the window sill in the foreground. I don't usually see such things in CGI" – Why does it matter whether the window sill in the foreground, or for that matter, the landscape and sky in the background are real or CGI? In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if they *were* real! Why go to the trouble of rendering something when you can find thousands of photographs on the web? But the plane in the center of the picture is definitely rendered. The skin just looks "off".

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes, this has been confirmed below

Comment: The amateurish wing-fuselage integration gives this away as one of the many scams with electric aircraft which circulate today. Every naive fellow thinks after Tesla there must follow electric airliners. Do the numbers and see for yourself how realistic this is.

Comment: @PeterKämpf you mean it looks like the wings are glued on?

Comment: @Abdullah: Yes, and there is litte structure to support asymmetrical loads. With lowered flaps there is a huge hole, lowering their effectiveness. Next, the thing is unstable without thrust. This is a problem in a descent and when batteries are empty. No sane FAA official would sign off on this. Again, looks like a scam.

Comment: @PeterKämpf I suppose the stability might be provided by airflow around and through the engine nacelle?

Comment: @PeterKämpf Ampaire AFAIK is currently converting existing planes (twin otters etc) to electric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called the Ampaire Tailwind, and as [this article explains](http://sustainableskies.org/ampaire-zero-emission-airplane/), it only exists in scale models and renderings at the moment.

Comment: this sounds like a stupid kind of thing for me to miss